# Visual Studio Code 1.51.1 not launching on Ubuntu 20.10 (ERROR: GLIBC_2.29' not found)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, glibc

**VSCODE VER: 1.51.1**

This shows up with `code --verbose`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
(code:29555): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:20:59.732: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
(code:29555): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:20:59.735: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3316:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
(code:29555): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:20:59.736: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3778:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
[29587:1127/102100.107310:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(286)] Failed to load libGL.so.1: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1)
[29587:1127/102100.108370:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(152)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[main 2020-11-27T13:21:00.129Z] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir
[main 2020-11-27T13:21:00.131Z] Lifecycle#kill()
```

As I ran `ldd --version` I found I'm running `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.32-0ubuntu3) 2.32`.

Could this version mismatch be the problem? How can I downgrade GLIBC to 2.29 (or upgrade VSCode to use ver 2.32), and not break any other software?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this is a cross-compiling issue.

try using snapcraft to install visual studio code

> sudo apt update

> sudo apt install snapd

then

> sudo snap install code --classic

https://snapcraft.io/install/code/ubuntu